# How to validate the datetime type field in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

```
array(
    'type' => 'datetime', 
    'id' => 'fromdatetime', 
    'label' => 'Display Start Date',
    'desc' => '', 
    'class' => 'span3', 
    'default' => post_default('bsdatetime', $package_info->display_start_date), 
    'options' => '', // array in case of dropdown, checkbox and radio buttons), I have a date time field like above.
```

in my model I set validation rules like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fromdatetime', 'From Date', 'required');
```

But I got my output as 'You have some errors in the form, please check and try again.' But not showing From date required.. how to rectify

Comment: did you use set_rules in a function?

Comment: use required field in view page

Comment: instead of id use name attribute.in ur array put 'name'=>'fromdatetime'!!

Comment: s i set rules in function but not works